# How to protect database connections from rogue developers?

Tags: python, database, security, cassandra, environment-variables

If you're building a system that has three databases - dev, testing and live, and you write a module to connect to the database, how do you make sure that a developer can not connect to the live database?

For example, you have different database clusters which are identified by variables. How do you stop the developer from simply replacing the "dev" variable with the "live" one?

Some potential solutions:

1. Use an environment variable (but couldn't the developer just change the environment variable on their local machine?)
2. Use some sort of config file which you then replace with a script when deploying to production. This makes sense and is quite simple...but is it the way these things are normally done?

The assumptions in this question are:

1. The database connection module is just part of the codebase, so any developer can see it and use it, and potentially change it. (Is this in itself bad?)

It would be great to know how to approach this issue - the stack is a Python server connecting to a Cassandra DB cluster, but where the cluster changes depending on whether it's dev, testing or live.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Access to a database should be regulated by credentials, not by a single variable. If developers should not connect to production they don't get the credentials for production.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. So in that case, are you saying the connection code for the database should live elsewhere, and developers should connect to it through some authenticated (http) API?

Comment: I did not say anything like that.

Comment: Ok, sorry. How do you suggest organising the system?

Comment: You still haven't understood by first comment. But anyway credentials management and system architecture are both not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I didn’t realise this wasn’t the place, sorry. But thank you for your helpful first response and for pointing out the problems with my question.

Answer (score 2):

Most common 2 solutions for this are (normally used together):

1. Firewall, production servers should have strict access rules so that at the very least apart from intra-cluster communication that might be free, all other exterior channels need to be pre-approved, so for examples only IPs assigned to the devops team or DBAs can even try to access the machines.
2. Use credentials. Most frameworks support some form or the other of application.properties/application.yaml/application.conf. Spring boot for example can read files with the name application.properties that are in the same folder as the jar and then use those values to override the ones bundled into the jar. So that you can override the user and password for the database in the production environment, where the dev should not have access.

So:
Dev has access trough the firewall to the dev server and also the user/password to it. This way he can experiment and develop with no problems. Depending on the organization tho' he might sue a local database so this may not apply.
When you go up to test/preprod/prod, the application should be configured to read the connection details from a file or as starting parameters so that the administrator or the dev-ops team can change them to be medium specific. This is also important as not to have the same credentials across all DBs.

For specific info regarding authentication on Cassandra, you can start here: [docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/security.html)

Hope this helped,
Cheers!